# .map followed by .result() and/or client.gather() results in a crash if workers are remote

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a need to call a function which does complicated things; and which needs to be iterated over a few hundred thousand times (think monte carlo simulation). I'm here because it didn't work with dask in my setup (first time user). So, i reduced the code to barebones (see below) to determine whether its the human, the environment, or both :-). Hoping the gurus here could help me out?

**code**

```
def do(x):
    y = x**2.0 
    return y
client = Client("tcp://10.61.68.34:8786")
x=[]
x = client.map(do, range(0, 1799))
r =[]
for i in x:
    r.append(i.result())
print(r)
del x
```

**SETUP**
**Scheduler**: *ip1, vmware vm, windows os, 128 cores, 200GB RAM, py 3.9, dask 2021.9.1* 
**Worker**: *same as above*

**Network**: intra- node (within 1 single node), Inbound rule allows incoming TCP connections to 8786, 8787. No specific rule for connections to ephemeral port is required because scheduler will communicate back to workers using the worker's ephemeral port used for TCP SYN packet.

launching scheduler using CLI:

> dask-scheduler.exe

launching worker using CLI:

> dask-worker.exe --nprocs 100 --nthreads 1 tcp://<<ip1..>>:8786

dask.yml has:

```
distributed:
  version: 2

  adaptive:
    interval: 1s
    target-duration: 15m

  admin:
    tick:
      interval: 20ms 
      limit: 300s 
  
  comm:
    retry:
      count: 5 
      offload: 100MiB
    
    zstd:
      level: 15 
      threads:0   # need to respect Python's GIL as not all delayed code handles dask objects
  
  deploy:
    lost-worker-timeout: 30s  
    cluster-repr-interval: 750ms 

  logging:
      distributed: debug
      distributed.client: debug
      bokeh: critical
      tornado: critical
      tornado.application: error

  scheduler:
    bandwidth: 10000000000    # 10 Gb/s even though LAN is capable of 100Gbps
    default-data-size: 100kiB
    events-cleanup-delay: 300s
    idle-timeout: 1h    
  
  worker:
    connections:            # Maximum concurrent connections for data
      outgoing: 300          # This helps to control network saturation
      incoming: 300
    lifetime:
      duration: 1800s
```

in iPython (from VSCode-- environment is set right), once map completes

```
after <Future: finished, type: float, key: do-b4e893e37f05790c2d90f6f7a57bc865>,
```

calling x[0].result() yields expected result (1.0)
calling x[1].result() yields expected result (4.0)
calling custom range

```
for i in range(2,10):
 y.append(x[i].result())
print(y)
```

also prints expected answer.
**CONCLUSION**: *code functions as desired*

Now, when workers are launched froma different machine (no local workers present anymore)
**Scheduler**: *ip1, vmware vm, windows os, 128 cores, 200GB RAM, dask 2021.9.1* 
**Worker**: *ip2, vmware vm, windows os, dask 2021.9.1*
**Noteworthy mentions**: 100Gbps network link between these two machines, firewall allows 8786, 8786 inbound on both

iPython output when calling the for loop; it goes on ad-inifinitium (until manual interruption):

```
distributed.client - DEBUG - Waiting on futures to clear before gather
distributed.comm.tcp - DEBUG - Setting TCP keepalive: idle=10, interval=2
distributed.comm.tcp - DEBUG - Setting TCP keepalive: idle=10, interval=2
distributed.comm.tcp - DEBUG - Setting TCP keepalive: idle=10, interval=2
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-9755ae4fe21461f71d76472d06ed69b7'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-4393edb8f90330ff85a14a347b57275f'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-b2354f9980c5f46e83153d4f2583f6f1'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-fa2cd7fe07c50c80dda8b5a308a7655c'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-80e7f4ee2b14bc0276a09b77db1e9d43'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-16311a9900ff7294aef0f0f3432b82fb'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-8ba4db219b30ddb8ee8ed086c752e72c'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-37eb0abfc3030871834fbb4ce6fdcf6e'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-5f894a60cd293af00b628a1c9d6972d0'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-e762686340db94c9b9617ba959694ecf'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-4e270441aebb8ed2a00f48ca3fc0391b'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-b1bd0b36b8e3b282d2caf42d373ccedd'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-a93dc9cc91d1a7e3fa7bc88673b7e33e'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-68324d1e2f16f3dd3ed2a4521280a1f1'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-94e3a7bdb4065cf34d47f6667ed5a695'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-0dbc31f32cb02f4925ca30ac92064eb1'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-70336d000742ece9b066b6c111f20fd3'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-ecd6c5c5caf0fe8d5499576f9f53764e'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-cb1d841d06994f4f5cba045e2c65e881'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-3015b21187427be5873d6477544063ae'}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'lost-data', 'key': 'do-f63da4cc3e1e26d64cc927f622d2631b'}
...
```

scheduler's sample output:

```
distributed.core - DEBUG - Message from 'tcp://<i3p>:53905': {'op': 'heartbeat_worker', 'address': 'tcp://<ip2>:53784', 'now': 1633623013.8946366, 'metrics': {'executing': 0, 'in_memory': 29, 'ready': 0, 'in_flight': 0, 'bandwidth': {'total': 10000000000, 'workers': {}, 'types': {}}, 'spilled_nbytes': 0, 'cpu': 0.0, 'memory': 104374272, 'time': 1633623013.8877068, 'read_bytes': 6227.017170580167, 'write_bytes': 19296.954301894224, 'read_bytes_disk': 0.0, 'write_bytes_disk': 10238.384044113825}, 'executing': {}, 'reply': True}
distributed.core - DEBUG - Calling into handler heartbeat_worker
```

bokeh status shows no errors.

lets pick a sample task from above logs to check its status @ worker:

```
distributed.worker - DEBUG - Send compute response to scheduler: do-b6553fa57215f934079c36275fe3985d, {'op': 'task-finished', 'status': 'OK', 'nbytes': 24, 'type': <class 'float'>, 'start': 1633623109.3889816, 'stop': 1633623109.3890078, 'thread': 14244, 'key': 'do-b6553fa57215f934079c36275f**e3985d**'}
```

once all tasks have state 'task-finished' at worker, debug messages only indicate normal heartbeat messages nothing special.

But, no result! Both scheduler + worker logs show activity, but thats it.

local output (iPython or VSCode run) shows:

```
    distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling {'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473': ('tcp://10.61.68.33:54198',)}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Waiting on futures to clear before gather
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'key-in-memory', 'key': 'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473'}
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling {'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473': ('tcp://10.61.68.33:54264',)}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Waiting on futures to clear before gather
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'key-in-memory', 'key': 'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473'}
distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 1 keys, rescheduling {'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473': ('tcp://10.61.68.33:54198',)}
distributed.client - DEBUG - Waiting on futures to clear before gather
distributed.client - DEBUG - Client receives message {'op': 'key-in-memory', 'key': 'do-473302f1b42c06c5a75fe179c7ffe473'}
```

and after few re-tries, it gives up, throws an exception, and program ends. *This happens every single time i run it with a remote worker*.

Behavior gets really weird if same code is re-factored using .persist() followed by client.gather(). In that case, workers get into, upon task completion, 'task forgotten' state and force-close the connection. I am happy to start a separate thread on it. But, i'm sure its something very basic that is tripping me here. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: this looks like it might be an issue with your networking or port whitelisting? can you include more detail about your distributed setup? how are you creating your cluster/workers? what kind of hardware/network/dask deployment etc. See the docs here on [setting up the networking when running workers manually from the cli](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/setup/cli.html#handling-ports). You may need to whitelist additional ports to cover the workers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Editing the post to include more of the networking setup. If networking was the issue then no requests should be served i.e. scheduler shouldn't even find the workers, right?

Comment: Took Michael Delgado’s suggestion. Disabled firewall. Works like a charm now! Thanks! 
So, it must be a port block issue. What would help alleviate the issue? 1) use a certain port range to launch workers? If so, how many? Does each thread within a process get its own socket? What happens if sockets in the given range are unavailable at execution time  2) 8686,8687 were already enabled in the fw to allow inbound connection from ephemeral ports. This usually means outbound direction between those socket pairs should work but it didn’t. Rather strange, no?

Comment: Tbh I think there's too much going on in your question and you probably got a number of people glancing at the wall of text and giving up. Now that you know what the issue is I'd ask a new question that is super focused on this networking issue, and provide your full network and dask setup but nothing else. This is a great question and I think you could get some help if you repost. I don't know how to solve this specific question but I'm sure if you provide the code you use to set up your local and remote you might get something. Good luck!